# Show navigationDrawer when swiping View Pager on the first page

Tags: android, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

I have a ViewPager. Now I need to add the NavigationDrawer. If the user is on the first page of the viewPager(the left-side first page) and he swipes from left to right, I need to show the Navigation Drawer. How can I achieve that? Do I have to override OnTouch listeners?
In other words I need the NavigationDrawer to appear by swiping whole scree, and not only the edge of the screen

Comment: have you implemented the whole the thing ? as the Navigation drawer is automatically opened up on swiping from left screen edge on any fragment you are.

Comment: @twntee yes, but I need it to be swiped not only from the edge of the screen on the first page of the view pager.

Answer (score 2):

```
private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mPageChangeListener =

        new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            private int times = 0;

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                                       int positionOffsetPixels) {

                Log.d(TAG, "position:" + position
                        + "\noffset: " + positionOffset
                        + "\npixels: " + positionOffsetPixels);

                if (position == 0 && positionOffset == 0 && positionOffsetPixels == 0) {
                    times++;
                    if (times >= 3) {
                        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mNavigationView);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {}

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    times = 0;
                }
            }
        };
```

You need to count the times of position == 0 && positionOffset == 0 && positionOffsetPixels == 0, because situation would happen when page_1 to page_0

Answer (score 1):

Set a PageChangeListener on your view pager

```
pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.tutorial_pager);
        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                    int postitionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

Then in onPageScrolled use the position == 1 and the position offset to trigger a mNavigationDrawer.openDrawer(gravity)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to create a custom View Pager and override the `onTouchEvent` method to detect when you're on the first page and scrolling from left to right and make it open the navigation drawer